# Why isn't my total cross-site reputation showing up on my user badge in "recent followers" on Area 51?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

I have a few hundred points from [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com) and [cooking.stackexchange.com](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), and those show up on my network profile, but they don't show up on parts of Area 51. Here's the view of my badge from http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30295/botany:

[image]

It says 51 points for me, but misses my points from other Stack Exchange sites, whereas other people show total points including other Stack Exchange sites. Why is this?

---

**update**: so I've got my 200 points on english.* as of some time yesterday, and have re-associated my accounts. The little icons still don't show up on area51:

[image]

---

**update**: *now* it works:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't show your reputation in other SE sites because in none of the SE sites you have a reputation of at least 200.
It is not a bug; it is how it works: only the sites where your reputation is greater than (or equal to) 200 are shown in Area 51. This is documented in [the site FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#network):

> #### What about my reputation on other Stack Exchange Network sites?
>
> If you have more than 200 reputation on associated accounts on other sites, you'll earn a one-time bonus of 100 reputation, **and we'll show your total reputation in your user information.** This is an easy way for others to see at-a-glance your achievements across the entire network!

Comment: oh, ok -- thanks for explaining!  it would be nice if these rules were written down somewhere.

Comment: @sibbaldiopsis: [they are...](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#network)

Comment: Hmmm... well, there are several places where user information is shown, one is the Network Profile page, and another is the icon-at-a-glance shown in committers. It would be nicer if somewhere (either the FAQ or an advanced FAQ) showed more detailed information, including things like what the magic formula is to get a site into the beta phase, or whatever.

Comment: @sibbaldiopsis: there's additional documentation in the works; keep an eye on the blog.

Comment: @Shog9 So once you have 200 in *one*, then it shows the total from *all*?  As opposed to showing the total of only those sites with >200?

Comment: @Renesis Only the sites where you have a reputation of at least 200 are shown in Area 51; actually, Area 51 shows the 6 SE sites where you have the higher reputation.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: so your answer was helpful but there still seems to be some kind of bug.